# Removing an FCurve

Tags: python, scripting, graph-editor, fcurves

I'm trying to delete an `F-Curve`. I'm aware that an F-Curve can be deleted when iterating through `bpy.data.actions` and using the [ActionFCurves.remove](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.ActionFCurves.html#bpy.types.ActionFCurves.remove) method. In a case such as this, however, I'm not sure how to get to the F-Curve's ActionFCurves.

```py
fcurves = bpy.context.visible_fcurves[:]
for fcurve in fcurves:
    if fcurve.mute:
        #deletion code goes here
```

Can anyone please advise on how to delete an F-Curve without having to loop through the `bpy.data.actions`? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you can get the action from the fcurve with the id_data attribute (since actions are an ID type):

```
for fcurve in bpy.context.visible_fcurves :
    if fcurve.mute:
        action = fcurve.id_data
        action.fcurves.remove(fcurve)
```

i changed a bit the beginnig of your code, you can also go for a one liner :

```
for fcurve in [fcurve for fcurve in bpy.context.fcurves if fcurve.mute] :
    action = fcurve.id_data
    action.fcurves.remove(fcurve)
```

Comment: This helped me SO much, thank you!!!!